# Question about using resolution to find a refutation about some clauses

Tags: artificial-intelligence, theorem-proving

I'm doing my homework for artificial intelligence course, and I'm currently stuck on a question about finding a refutation about some clauses.

I tried many ways of finding the refutation about those clauses, however, it either ended up with the same goal clause that I was trying to find, or ended up with more and more clauses.

Here are the clauses written in Prolog format:

```
% A1
i(e, X, X).

% A2
i(X, e, X).

% A3
i(comp(X), X, e).

% A4
i(X, comp(X), e).

% A51
i(U, Z, W) :- i(X, Y, U), i(Y, Z, V), i(X, V, W).

% A52
i(X, V, W) :- i(X, Y, U), i(Y, Z, V), i(U, Z, W).

% A6
i(X, X, e).

% A7
i(a, b, c).

% A8
-i(b, a, c)
```

If you have any idea, please help me out, thank you very much!

Edit:

I wanted to show you my tries, but it was handwritten and it is hard to type them out. Basically, I tried resolve A8 and A51 first with unifier e1 = [U/b, Z/a, W/c], and it ended up with -i(b, a, c). I also tried resolve A1 and A51 first with unifier e2 = [U/e, Z/X, W/X] and it ended up with all the possible combinations of -i(M, M, M) where M belongs to {a, b, c, e} for example: -i(b, b, a)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not much good at Prolog, but here is an Isabelle proof of the refutation (for fun).

```
lemma so55485292:
  fixes i a b c e
  assumes A1:  "⋀X. i(e, X, X)"
      and A51: "⋀U V W X Y Z. ⟦ i(X, Y, U); i(Y, Z, V); i(X, V, W) ⟧ ⟹ i(U, Z, W)"
      and A52: "⋀U V W X Y Z. ⟦ i(X, Y, U); i(Y, Z, V); i(U, Z, W) ⟧ ⟹ i(X, V, W)"
      and A6:  "⋀X. i(X, X, e)"
      and A7:  "i(a, b, c)"
      and A8:  "¬i(b, a, c)"
    shows False
proof -
  have swap: "⋀s t u. i(s, t, u) ⟹ i (u, t, s)"
  proof -
    fix s t u
    assume "i(s, t, u)"
    moreover have "i(t, t, e)" by (rule A6)
    moreover have "i(s, e, s)"
    proof (rule A52)
      show "i(s, s, e)" by (rule A6)
      show "i(s, s, e)" by (rule A6)
      show "i(e, s, s)" by (rule A1)
    qed
    ultimately show "i(u, t, s)" by (rule A51)
  qed

  have "i (a, c, b)"
  proof (rule A52)
    show "i(a, a, e)" by (rule A6)
    show "i(a, b, c)" by (rule A7)
    show "i(e, b, b)" by (rule A1)
  qed
  from this have "i (b, c, a)" by (rule swap)
  moreover have "i(c, b, a)" using A7 by (rule swap)
  ultimately have "i(b, a, c)" using A7 by (rule A52)

  from A8 and this show ?thesis ..
qed
```

(It's a shame that there is no syntax highlighting for the beautiful Isar language...)

`A2`, `A3`, and `A4` are redundant. Isabelle can show that a proof exists very quickly using `sledgehammer`. It took a bit longer and some trial and error to tease an explanatory Isar proof out of the automatic proof.

For Prolog, you probably need to eliminate the *swap* lemma by cut elimination.